# SQL Join two tables where the a criteria does not match

Tags: sql, join

I have a table with owners and a table with cars, I'd like to join the two tables to show all the owners that do not have a car "make" of "ford" or "dodge", including those that don't have a car. The owner can have more than one car. How would I construct this query? Thanks

Rik

Comment: Edit the questions add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Are you asking about the entity structure or only the query? Either way the structure is required to answer this question.

Comment: Hi. This is an obvious duplicate. Please always google many clear, concise & specificversions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particularstrings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to yoursearches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title &keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT o.*
FROM owners o
LEFT JOIN cars c ON c.ownerid = o.id AND c.make in ('ford', 'dodge')
WHERE c.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT o.*
FROM owners o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cars c WHERE c.carid = o.carid AND c.make in ('ford', 'dodge'));
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with a join?

Comment: @Rik . . . I think the intent is clearer with `NOT EXISTS`.